# XMLHttpRequest is showing a msg error in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I did a function to show a div when i open my html(its working fine, the div shows at open), but i get this error:

[image]

```
   var getJSON = function (url, callback) {
      var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ajax.open('GET', url, true);
      ajax.responseType = 'json';
      ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var status = ajax.status;
        if (status === 200) {
          callback(status, ajax.response);
        } else {
          callback(null, ajax.response);
        }
      };
      ajax.send();
    };

getJSON('games.json', function (err, data) {
  if (err === null) {
    console.log('Error' + err);
  } else {
    var bets = document.getElementById('bets-container-lotos');
    bets.innerHTML = '';
    bets.innerHTML +=
      '<button id="bets-lotofacil-color"  class="bets-lotofacil" onclick=lotofacil()>' +
      data.types[0].type +
      '</button>';
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is the code for the `callback` function?

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's the `function (err, data) {` part.

Comment: The error means that `ajax.response` is `null`.

Comment: Why is status 200 an error?

Comment: what type of url is `games.json`?

Comment: Also, wait for the request to complete before your callback is executed

Comment: You need to wait for `ajax.readyState == 4` before trying to process the response.

Comment: @YogeshBhatt — A fairly sensible one if you want to retrieve a static JSON file from the same directory as the HTML document.

Comment: Is there any browser or user agent support the use of  `responseType` and `response` on `XMLHttpRequest` which doesn't support simply using the `onload` handler to handle the response and `onerror` to handle an error? I am wondering why people use `onreadystatechange` these days.